# Python Tkinter Title issue

Tags: python, tkinter

Every time i write in the title for Tkinter it creates a new window instead of adding the title to the frame. using Root.Title('') so the Tk stays at the top of my main window

Comment: Can you please add your code, that produces this behaviour?

Comment: add code to question, not to comment

Comment: You use `Tk()` twice - first in `root=Tk()` second `SampleApp(tk.Tk)` - and it can be problem

Comment: @furas: I'm curious how you know that. The question doesn't show any code, and I'm not seeing any edit history of code that was edited out.

Comment: @BryanOakley there was code in comment (before my "add code to question, not to comment") but OP deleted it

Answer (score 0):

You use `Tk()` two times - first `root = tk.Tk()`, second `SampleApp(tk.Tk)`.

If you create class using `Tk` then you don't need `root = tk.Tk()`

Simple example

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("The Title")
        tk.Label(self, text="Hello World of Tkinter").pack()       

SampleApp().mainloop()
```

---

BTW: if you will need second window use `Toplevel`

Answer (score -1):

It may be a typo in your post but 'Title' will produce and error.  The property is 'title' (lowercase).

This code snippet works on my mac running Python 2.7.

```
from Tkinter import *

main = Tk()
main.title('The Title')

mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it appears to be asking for clarification.

Comment: Sorry Brian.  I have edited so it now reads as an answer.  I am assuming that this answers the OP's question though I may have misunderstood.